# How to open a form view (wizard) after button click in odoo 16 without closing all existing opened form view (wizard)

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

How to open a form view (wizard) after button click in odoo 16 without closing all existing opened form view (wizard)

```
def get_preview(self):
    email_preview_action = self.env['ir.actions.actions']._for_xml_id("survey_custom.wizard_email_preview_action")
    context = {
        'default_subject': self.subject,
        'default_body_html': self.body_html,
        'default_mail_template_id': self.id,
    }
    email_preview_action['context'] = context

    return email_preview_action
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't without customization and that will all depends on what you wanna accomplish with that. If you just wanna open an action not related to the current one you could implement a custom action client for that matter